# Populate already split numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I am trying to avoid using list of lists and appending during my loop, so I've figured I can create a large `np.zeros` array, then use `np.split` to split it in batches, and populate the batches. The code looks like this:

```
N = inputData.size - len(inputData.columns) * (days_decay + 1)
all_params = np.zeros([N, 1])
all_params = np.split(all_params, len(inputData.columns))
for i, fx in enumerate(inputData.columns):
    fx_spots = inputData[fx]
    [ewma_vola, rets, ewma_mean] = compute_ewma(fx_spots, 0.98, 124)
    param_ts = rets[(days_decay + 1):] / ewma_vola[:-1]
    param_ts = param_ts.reshape(param_ts.shape[0], 1)
    all_params[:][i] = param_ts
```

Note that at the end, for each iteration, `all_params[:][i].shape == param_ts.shape`. For some reason, the arrays within the array are all `np.zeros` after the loop instead of being populated. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS I also do not know if this is going to be faster than list of lists and appending, but I wanted to experiment a little bit as well. It might not even be worth it at the end.

Comment: Maybe you mean `all_params[i][:]` ?

Comment: It worked with +=instead of =, but I don't know why it wouldn't work with only =